# Views event listing by date with up/down infinite scroll

Tags: views, datetime

I have a content type called "**Event**" which contains a "**Date**" field. What I want to achive:

**1)** Create a view which can display 5 events sorted by "Date" and displayed as following:

- 2 events which are previous to the current date
- 1 event which is of current or the nearest date
- 2 events which are following current or the nearest date

**2)** When these things are ready I want to have a possibility to:

- **scroll up** and dynamically load 5 more "previous" events
- **scroll down** and dynamically load 5 more "following" events

I understand how to do it with 2 different views displays (one for current and upcoming events and a block before with past events), but the thing is that I need to create a page slider (where each fullscreen slide is one event) which can be slide both before and forward over all site events (there may be a lot of them, so i can't just load all events at once and need to do it dynamically when sliding over). Will be very thankful for any idea how to create such a display using one view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve your requirement by following below steps.

1. Install [Views Field View](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_field_view) module.
2. Create first view of Event content type with 2 events which are previous to the current date
3. Create second view of Event content type with 2 events which are greater than current date.
4. Now create on third view with current date and into its header part add first view and into footer part add second view using Views Field View. Follow screenshot attached below

[image]

Regarding **scroll down** functionality install [Views Load More](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_load_more) module.

I don't know how to achieve **scroll up** functionality. It something like you have to write custom thing.

Comment: Thanks a lot about your idea. But it seams that in this case I will get 3 different displays inside html structure, so it will be a bit problematically to use js slide code over them. In a best case I want to achive a display which hasa liniar structure of rows with all that content. Anyway, many thanks :)